# pandas representing datetime with midnight as hour 24

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working in python pandas and I am doing the following:

```
StDt = datetime(2018, 1, 1, 1, 0)
EnDt = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 0)

allHours = pd.date_range(StDt, EnDt, freq='H').to_pydatetime()
```

The midnight hours are represented as:

```
datetime(2018, 1, 3, 0, 0)
datetime(2018, 1, 5, 0, 0)
```

Is it possible to create the series in a way such that midnight is represented as hour 24 of previous day

i.e. the above two cases will look as:

```
datetime(2018, 1, 2, 24, 0)
datetime(2018, 1, 4, 24, 0)
```

i.e. I am looking for following:

```
datetime(2018, 1, 3, 0, 0) = datetime(2018, 1, 2, 24, 0)
datetime(2018, 1, 5, 0, 0) = datetime(2018, 1, 4, 24, 0)
```

Edit:
My particular situation requires working in hour ending world and that is how the convention is in what I am working in.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Maybe rethink what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using datetimes, this is not possible. Python simply doesn't accept `datetime(2018, 1, 2, 24, 0)` as a valid time.

There was a request in 2010 to allow for this time to be accepted

- [**Issue 10427:** 24:-00 Hour in DateTime](https://bugs.python.org/issue10427)

which was rejected.

My only suggestion would be to consider whether you *really* need this time depicted as you outlined. For actual data manipulation, it should not make any difference as any operations you'd like to do in Pandas with datetimes will conform to this same restriction anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with similar data, and found it useful to consider that Hour Ending data labeled 1-24 is the equivalent of Hour Beginning data labeled 0-23.

So you'll have to change your rule set notation, but it should be a straightforward change.